# How to add Bodies to a SKPhysicsWorld

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm developing a running game for iOS devices and have run into a problem.  I created a subclass for a game tile which is 4 screen lengths long. The game tile will have some nodes which are obstacles. I have a scene which creates the player, some background decorations, and particle systems.  I need to add the obstacle nodes to the physics simulation in the scene so that I can detect when they contact.  I'm not sure how to do that...  Is there another solution that would be simpler? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Simpler than the way you're not sure about how to do? ;)
I you haven't already I suggest you read through the Physics section of the programming guide, this should help what to do and how to do it:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html

Comment: @LearnCocos2d: Since I will be adding the SKSpriteNode subclass (the tile) to the scene, then I guess the obstacles would be considered in the physics simulation because they are indirectly part of the SKScene?

Comment: a physics body is connected with a node, and when the node is added as child of another node so will the body be part of the world